# Extract Names aov function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the names and p-values for given effects from an aov summary in R.  To make my problem clearer, the aov summary looks like this:

```
Error: subj
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Group      1    9.6   9.585   1.403  0.241
Residuals 58  396.3   6.832               

Error: subj:StimProb
               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value Pr(>F)    
StimProb        1  739.0   739.0 2939.367 <2e-16 ***
StimProb:Group  1    0.2     0.2    0.688   0.41    
Residuals      58   14.6     0.3                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subj:StimVal
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
StimVal        1  0.126 0.12585   0.558  0.458
StimVal:Group  1  0.026 0.02609   0.116  0.735
Residuals     58 13.074 0.22541               

Error: subj:StimProb:StimVal
                       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
StimProb:StimVal        1  0.255 0.25512   0.820  0.369
StimProb:StimVal:Group  1  0.036 0.03586   0.115  0.735
Residuals              58 18.044 0.31110               

Error: Within
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 480   3283   6.839
```

I am trying to obtain a list of names/pvalues, such as:

```
Group = 2.41
Residuals = NA
StimProb = <2e-16
StimProb:Group = 0.41
...and so forth
```

I was able to write code that extracts the p-values (which seems to be a widespread problem if you search previous forums):

```
 # p values
 p <- NA
 for(i in 1:length(amp_aov_3)){
    tmp_p  <- lapply(amp_aov_3[[i]], function(aov_sum){aov_sum$'Pr(>F)'})
    tmp_p <- unlist(tmp_p)
    p <- c(p, tmp_p)
 }
```

But I cannot figure out where the names of the given effects are stored. I can only access the main header using the names function (e.g., 'Error: subj ').  Any advice?

Here is a dump of the amp_aov_3 (i.e., aov summary) variable so people can play with the code.

```
structure(list(`Error: subj` = structure(list(structure(list(
    Df = c(1, 58), `Sum Sq` = c(9.58542761189546, 396.251513143065
    ), `Mean Sq` = c(9.58542761189546, 6.83192264039767), `F value` = c(1.40303515078115, 
    NA), `Pr(>F)` = c(0.24104729974717, NA)), .Names = c("Df", 
"Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F value", "Pr(>F)"), class = c("anova", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c("Group    ", "Residuals"))), class = c("summary.aov", 
"listof")), `Error: subj:StimProb` = structure(list(structure(list(
    Df = c(1, 1, 58), `Sum Sq` = c(738.998618354635, 0.173077631291876, 
    14.5820237916664), `Mean Sq` = c(738.998618354635, 0.173077631291876, 
    0.251414203304593), `F value` = c(2939.36702318812, 0.688416282838996, 
    NA), `Pr(>F)` = c(2.16974416659602e-51, 0.410105585145585, 
    NA)), .Names = c("Df", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F value", "Pr(>F)"
), class = c("anova", "data.frame"), row.names = c("StimProb      ", 
"StimProb:Group", "Residuals     "))), class = c("summary.aov", 
"listof")), `Error: subj:StimVal` = structure(list(structure(list(
    Df = c(1, 1, 58), `Sum Sq` = c(0.12584744523128, 0.0260871639459221, 
    13.0738086981129), `Mean Sq` = c(0.12584744523128, 0.0260871639459221, 
    0.225410494795049), `F value` = c(0.558303398187847, 0.115731807295137, 
    NA), `Pr(>F)` = c(0.45796319404567, 0.734939632080671, NA
    )), .Names = c("Df", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F value", "Pr(>F)"
), class = c("anova", "data.frame"), row.names = c("StimVal      ", 
"StimVal:Group", "Residuals    "))), class = c("summary.aov", 
"listof")), `Error: subj:StimProb:StimVal` = structure(list(structure(list(
    Df = c(1, 1, 58), `Sum Sq` = c(0.255118030657232, 0.035859237207785, 
    18.0436753630829), `Mean Sq` = c(0.255118030657232, 0.035859237207785, 
    0.311097851087636), `F value` = c(0.820057193469219, 0.115266746724276, 
    NA), `Pr(>F)` = c(0.368910019571438, 0.735452223019943, NA
    )), .Names = c("Df", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F value", "Pr(>F)"
), class = c("anova", "data.frame"), row.names = c("StimProb:StimVal      ", 
"StimProb:StimVal:Group", "Residuals             "))), class = c("summary.aov", 
"listof")), `Error: Within` = structure(list(structure(list(Df = 480, 
    `Sum Sq` = 3282.85398452856, `Mean Sq` = 6.83927913443451, 
    `F value` = NA_real_, `Pr(>F)` = NA_real_), .Names = c("Df", 
"Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F value", "Pr(>F)"), class = c("anova", 
"data.frame"), row.names = "Residuals")), class = c("summary.aov", 
"listof"))), .Names = c("Error: subj", "Error: subj:StimProb", 
"Error: subj:StimVal", "Error: subj:StimProb:StimVal", "Error: Within"
), class = "summary.aovlist")
```

Comment: Maybe the `broom` package can be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.  This function extracts p-values from the aov function in R.

```
get_p = function(aov_sum){
    p <- NA
    h <- NA
    for(i in 1:length(aov_sum)){
      # p values
      tmp_p  <- lapply(aov_sum[[i]], function(aov_sum2){aov_sum2$'Pr(>F)'})
      tmp_p <- unlist(tmp_p)
      p <- c(p, tmp_p)
      # headers
      tmp_h  <- row.names(aov_sum[i][[1]][[1]][1])
      h <- c(h, tmp_h)
    }
    h <- gsub(" ", "", h)
    names(p) <- h
    p <- p[is.na(p)==FALSE]
    return(p)
  }
```

Comment: This only works for `aovlist` class, i.e. when Error term is included.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been dormant for a long while, but from what @Jaap said, the best tidy solution I've seen is with `broom`.  Example from [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/broom/man/anova_tidiers.html)

```
a <- anova(lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec + disp, mtcars))
```

printing `a` in base functions looks like this:

```
a
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: mpg
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
wt         1 847.73  847.73 121.4366 1.082e-11 ***
qsec       1  82.86   82.86  11.8694  0.001817 ** 
disp       1   0.00    0.00   0.0001  0.990423    
Residuals 28 195.46    6.98                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Nice to just to look at, but not a very tidy method and the information isn't extractable easily. `broom` always exports things into a data frame with the names in their own column.

```
#from broom package
tidy(a) 
           term df        sumsq       meansq    statistic      p.value
    1        wt  1 8.477252e+02 8.477252e+02 1.214366e+02 1.081618e-11
    2      qsec  1 8.285831e+01 8.285831e+01 1.186944e+01 1.817334e-03
    3      disp  1 1.023935e-03 1.023935e-03 1.466785e-04 9.904229e-01
    4 Residuals 28 1.954626e+02 6.980807e+00           NA           NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether an Error term is included, the `aov` function returns either an `aov` or an `aovlist` object. Below are the functions to extract p values from either (as implemented in my [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/POSSA/index.html) as a single [`get_p`](https://github.com/gasparl/possa/blob/master/R/get_p.R) function; credit to **Nick** for the name).

```
get_p.aov <- function(x) {
    terms <- summary(x)[[1]]
    p = stats::setNames(as.list(terms$`Pr(>F)`), gsub(" ", "", rownames(terms)))
    return(p[-length(p)])
}

get_p.aovlist <- function(x) {
    aov_sum = summary(x)
    p = list()
    for (i in 1:length(names(aov_sum))) {
        terms <- aov_sum[[i]][[1]]
        p[[gsub(" ", "", names(aov_sum)[i])]] = stats::setNames(as.list(terms$`Pr(>F)`), gsub(" ", "", rownames(terms)))[-nrow(terms)]
    }
    return(p)
}
```